# What drawColor(-1) means in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to understand an android code

mCanvas.drawColor(-1);

What does the -1 mean ? What RGB value it equates to ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear that that function accepts any special values, so I'll guess it's just some really obscure way of specifying white.

Hex value of -1 is `0xFFFFFFFF`, which just breaks down into `R=255, G=255, B=255, A=255`, which is full white.

Answer (score 2):

The signed int value -1 corresponds to the unsigned int 0xFFFFFFFF (in case of 32-bits). Colors are encoded as 0xAARRGGBB, so -1 means white.